# Align N buttons left and 1 button right in ToolBar

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ToolBar that takes 100% width of its parent container. And I want to have some buttons on left side of toolbar (but1, but2) and one button (but3) on right side of toolbar. I mean

```
------------------------------------------------
| [but1][but2]                           [but3]|
------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to do without adding extra containers and toolbars? If yes, then how?

Comment: Isn't it a possibility to add two containers to you toolbar, and position the buttons within those two?

Comment: [`LayoutSampleCSS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/style_css.htm) is a complete example using `HBox`.